# Refused to load stylesheets because it violates Content Security Policies

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, ajax

I am trying to add jquery and css files to my .cshtml file, but I am getting Content Security Policy errors.

I already tried adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *.aspnetcdn.com/">` and stuff like that, but it doesn't work.

[Here are the errors that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwDJe.png)

And here is the .cshtml file:

```
@using Genesis.SharedLibrary.ViewModels.Genesis.ALG

@inject Genesis.Application.Services.Commons.IGenericServices _genericServices;
@{
    var staticFileVersion = _genericServices.GetAppSettingValue("OtherSettings", "StaticFileVersion");
}


@model List<TravelRequestAdminViewModel>

<body>
    @* DATA TABLE WITH SEVEN COLUMNS AND MANY ROWS *@
</body>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script src="~/shared/js/Views/travelRequestAdminScript.js?v=@staticFileVersion"></script>
```

Comment: check this [link](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/02/implementing-content-security-policy/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to relax the default policy for remote scripts

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://code.jquery.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://example.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';  media-src *">
```

Reference:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing

Comment: Did you read the reference? Everything is in there for the different domains from where you're trying to get the files